# SQL - Query the same column but with 2 different conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called Products which contains the entire catalog. That table has a unique Product_ID, the Category it belongs to, and then a field Available which shows in which countries (US, UK, DE, ...) the product can be sold. If a product can be sold on multiple then the combination Product_ID and Available looks like:

```
23523 DE
23523 UK
23523 US
...
```

I need to do a query that produces 3 columns:

```
Category   Total_Number_Products   DE_Number_Products
```

I can do this on 2 separate queries, one for Total_Number_Products and the other for DE_Number_Products, each one with a Count - the 1st one without any condition and the 2nd one checking if "Available = 'DE'".

How can I or should I query that same column with COUNT(Product_ID) twice on the same query, once for all the products and then for the DE specific products?

Answer (score 1):

Please consider this:

```
select category,
       count(*) total_number_products,
       sum(case available when 'DE' then 1 else 0 end) de_number_products
from products
group by category
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do conditional aggregation here:

```
select category,
    count(*) as total_number_products,
    count(case when country = 'DE' then 1 end) as DE_number_products
from your_table
group by category;
```